# Hot to unit test when content_type is dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to test my function that returns dictionary. I'm getting error **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content_type'**. How can I test if the response is a dictionary or not?

```
def response_get(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
    data = response.json()
    return data
```

```
def test_response_get(self):
    response = response_get('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/58611129-2dbc-4a81-a72f-77ddfc1b1b49')
    self.assertEqual(response.content_type, 'application/dict')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already returning a dict and there is no `content_type` on a dictionary.
Instead you can use `isinstance` and `assertTrue`.

```
import requests
import unittest

def response_get(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
    data = response.json()
    return data

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase): 

    def test_response_get(self):
        response = response_get('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/58611129-2dbc-4a81-a72f-77ddfc1b1b49')
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(response, dict))
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.966s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for !